# Text in SVG does not appear

Tags: javascript, svg

I`m trying to add text to a svg element with javascript.

Here is my javascript code:

```
var svg=document.getElementById("svgtext");
var newText = document.createElementNS(svg,"text");
newText.setAttributeNS(null,"x",0);     
newText.setAttributeNS(null,"y",50); 
newText.setAttributeNS(null,"font-size","100");
newText.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","black");
var textNode = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
newText.appendChild(textNode);
document.getElementById("gText").appendChild(newText);
```

and this is the HTML

```
         <svg id="svgtext" width=160px height=250px>
              <g id="gText">
                  <text x="0" y="15" fill="black">SVG!</text> 
              </g>
         </svg>
```

As you can see if I add manually some text, it works perfectly. When I try with javascript I can see it present in Chrome's inspector tool, but it just does not appear on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the wrong value to the first argument of createElementNS. It should be as below.§

```js
var newText = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
newText.setAttributeNS(null,"x",0);     
newText.setAttributeNS(null,"y",50); 
newText.setAttributeNS(null,"font-size","100");
newText.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","black");
var textNode = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
newText.appendChild(textNode);
document.getElementById("gText").appendChild(newText);
```

```html
         <svg id="svgtext" width="160px" height="250px">
              <g id="gText">
                  <text x="0" y="15" fill="black">SVG!</text> 
              </g>
         </svg>
```